# Dimension for UV unwrap

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I get a problem with UV mapping in Blender.
I do some render of architecture, and I get some walls of 2.25m height and 10m length.
So I did a picture of 1024px x 3072px to get a good resolution.
But when I unwrap (solid, cube, from view, etc), proportions are not good... (and I reset scale object to 1 before unwrapping).
It seems that if picture is 1024 x 1024px or 2048 x 2048, I don't get this problem.
Does someone can explain me the problem (and any solution?)  :-)

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: use "Project from view (Bounds)"  to get UVmap of the same size as the image